# Read data from HTML page and write to database in regular interval

Tags: php, html, database, store

I need to read temperature (simple number, that generates my arduino on ethernet) and store that number into database every few seconds. But I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I would use PHP with DOM parser, but I'm not sure how to do this without the php page being opened.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Can you please share some code that you have already implemented?

Comment: Well i know how to get data from html and store them to MySQL. But how can i run this php script without opening the page in browser ? I mean how to make the script run automatically ?

Comment: Cron-Job? If windows... Windows Task Scheduler with a Powershell script!

Comment: Cron-job seems fine for my needs. Im running apache on debian. Is there any way how to do that locally even on linux ?

Comment: Yeah cron-job is linux specifically, try this: https://www.taniarascia.com/setting-up-a-basic-cron-job-in-linux/

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you alot mate :))

Comment: @Scherby also see http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.no/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html